# Pigeon hole principle problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that for any $n+1$ integers $a_1,a_2,...,a_{n+1}$ there exist two integers $a_i$ and $ a_j$ with $i\neq j$, such that $a_i-a_j$ is divisible by n.

How would one prove this? If I have $n=5$ then there would be $5$ integers $1,2,3,4,5$ and their difference will always be one.

But since there are more integers than remainder because $n=5$ can only have $4$ remainders.

This means two integers must have same remainder. So does this mean they can be divided by the same number $n$?

Comment: If you have $n=5$ then you have 6 integers which might be 1,2,3,4,5,6.  Their differences are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm5$, because $i$ and $j$ can take any distinct values.

Comment: But the integers don't have to be consecutive, the proof doesn't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $n=5$ then you will have six integers ($n+1=6$), so for convenience let's assume $n=4$ and follow the example you have given where the numbers are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.

To understand the problem properly, you have to realise that you are allowed to take the difference between any pair of numbers, and not just those which are adjacent.

Here you have differences $5-4=4-3=3-2=2-1=1$, which you note in your question. But you also have $5-3=4-2=3-1=2$ and $5-2=4-1=3$ and finally $5-1=4$ which is divisible by $n=4$.

You are right to think about the remainders you get after dividing by $n$. What can you say about the difference between two numbers which leave the same remainder?

I think you have all the pieces there in your question - you just need to make sure you are clear in your thinking so you put them together in the right order.

Comment: I have taken the absolute value of differences and ignored the negative ones for the purpose of the above.

Comment: I see so you can subtract the integer in any order.

Comment: I see so so everyone integer on the list can be written as k(n)+r with k being an integer and r being the remainder. where k in an integer r is the remainder.